# PHP Equivalent of HttpPost Within a Class

Tags: php, asp.net-mvc

I've searched for a while on this, but haven't found much information. I'm using a MVC design in a PHP project and I want to keep the logic out of my Views, so I've been trying to see if I can do just that...

In C#/ASP.NET MVC you can use something that looks like this:

```
public void MyClass {      
[HttpPost]
      public IActionResult Index(string firstName)
      {
          return Content($"Hello {firstName}");
      }  
}
```

This makes the form post attributes inside of whichever class you need.

I'm wondering is there a way do this in PHP, where you can have the Post request inside of the class? Maybe something like this?

```
class MyClass {
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {
        // Do your thing here
    }
}
```

Comment: or `if(!empty($_POST))` but it has to be in a method body.  A better way it to use a more advanced routing system that allows you to bind functions to HTTP verbs. (something I plan to write one day)

Comment: Why can't you just name you methods `postIndex` and `getIndex`?

Comment: @tereško - He can, but his router has to call them, sort of my point.  I would probably name them `POST_index` and `GET_index` and then have the router try those when it's appropriate (method_exists) and fall back to the normal when not.  Just for example.

Comment: That's a hell of a lot like Java annotations. And the Doctrine Project has a [standalone annotation library](https://github.com/doctrine/annotations) used by doctrine itself, symfony, laravel and many others. I guess you could do it. Not sure how would you resolve conflicts...

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried,

```
respond('POST', '/', function ($request, $response) 
{
    $request->validate('url')->notNull();
    $response->url= $request->url;
    $response->render('any page');
});
```

Comment: No I have not. You can just throw this in your class? Or, do you have a link to more info on this?